# MapStruct using interface with Spring Boot causes NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring-boot, exception, interface, mapstruct

I have implemnted an interface for using `MapStruct`:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MapStructMapper {

    MapStructMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( MapStructMapper.class );

    MyApiModel myInternalClassToMyApiModel(MyDocument.MyInternalClass myInternalClass);
    MyDocument.MyInternalClass myApiModelToMyInternalClass(MyApiModel myApiModel);
}
```

When running the gradle build I get the following exception when tests are executed:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'MapStructMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

In my test class I currently have only:

```
@Autowired
protected MapStructMapper mapper;
```

and in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
```

How can I solve this problem and how can I invoke the mapping if I use MapStruct using an interface?

Comment: so did you solve the issue? facing exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Please check that you not only included the mapstruct dependencies but also the annotation processor in your build such that the `MapStructMapperImpl` is actually generated.

If it is indeed generated, you must make sure that it is included in the application context of your test. If you use `@SpringBootTest`, you need to make sure that the interface is declared in a package that is scanned by the component scan. If you construct a dedicated context with `@ContextConfiguration`, you need to list `MapStructMapperImpl.class` in the list that you pass to the parameter `classes` like you would with other classes annotated with `@Component`.